# Evaluate $f^{\prime}(0)$ where $f(x) = \begin{cases} g(x) \sin(1/x)& \mbox{if} \quad x \neq 0 \\ 0 &\mbox{if} \quad x = 0 \end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am trying to evaluate $f^\prime (0)$, where
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
g(x) \sin(1/x)& \mbox{if} \quad x \neq 0 \\
0 &\mbox{if} \quad  x = 0,
\end{cases}
$$
and $g(0) = g^{\prime}(0) = 0$.

I started by noting that $g$ is differentiable at $x = 0$, hence, $g$ is continuous at $x = 0$. Therefore, $$\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = g(0) = 0.$$

Now,

$$
f^\prime (0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} \stackrel{*}{=} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g(x) \sin (1/x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} g^\prime (x) \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}.
$$
I'm not too sure how to proceed.

I've already tried using L'Hospital's rule at $*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sandwich/pinching/squeezing theorem: if $x\ne0$ then
$$0\le\left|\frac{g(x)\sin(1/x)}{x}\right|\le\left|\frac{g(x)}{x}\right|$$
and
$$\frac{g(x)}{x}=\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}\to g'(0)=0$$
as $x\to0$.

Comment: Quick question, does this argument require that $g^\prime (x)$ be continuous, so that $\lim_{x \to 0} g^\prime (x) = g^\prime (0)$?

Comment: I don't think so: we didn't look at $\lim g'(x)$, only at $\lim(g(x)-g(0))/(x-0)$, which is by definition $g'(0)$ provided the limit exists, which in this question is given.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.